# Unity Canvas Scaller - Image height riddle

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have received an interesting problem that I couldn't solve. Maybe I am missing something.

Canvas 1 properties:

```
Render Mode - Screen Space - Overlay

Canvas Scaler:
UIScale mode: Scale With Screen Size
Reference resolution: 2960 x 1440
Screen match mode: Match Width or Height
Match: 1 
Reference pixels per unit: 100
```

Inside Canvas 1 we have an image with the following properties:

```
Rect Transform - full bottom stretch (Left / Right - 0)
Height: 100
Pos Y: 50
```

Canvas 2 properties:

```
Render Mode - Screen Space - Overlay

Canvas Scaler:
UIScale mode: Scale With Screen Size
Reference resolution: 1440 x 2560
Screen match mode: Expand
Reference pixels per unit: 100
```

Inside Canvas 2 we need to insert an image of height x that will have the same real height with image from Canvas 1

```
Rect Transform - full bottom stretch (Left / Right - 0)
Height: x
```

Consider the following real resolutions:

1. 1920 height x 1080 width (portrait)
2. 2778 height x 1284 width (portrait)

I need to know what would be a formula to solve this on paper.
We take the first resolution: 1920 x 1080 portrait mode.
If I duplicate the image from Canvas 1 into Canvas 2, the image from Canvas 2 will have a scale of 1.777778, so if we set the scale to 1, the real height will be 1.777778 x 100 = 177 units on height.

Canvas 1 has a scale factor of 1.333333 at 1920 x 1080 portrait resolution. (1920 / 1440 = 1.333333) because it is Match height of 1.
Canvas 2 has a scale factor of 0.75 because 1440 / 1920 = 0.75.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: If an Image GO is created and the Rect Transform for the Image is set to stretch, expand and cover the whole Canvas, then the size of the Canvas is irrelevant, no? Or am I missing something? (f.e. backgrounds). For instance, create a Panel to the height you need, such as the full height of the Canvas (since I understand that is what you want) and an Image GO as a child of the Panel GO with full height stretch. Then resizing can be done from the Panel directly. Is that what you need? I assume you mean from the Inspector, not programmatically (since that is not how uGUI is usually used).

Comment: @TheNomad From the game itself it is easy, you duplicate the gameobject from Canvas 1 and set parent on Canvas 2. From that, you have the scale 1.7778 and the real height value is 1.7778 x 100. The real question is how you calculate the formulas? How is Unity knowing that the scale is 1.7778?

Comment: They were asking based on those details, in Canvas 1, the image has height 100, what was the height in Canvas 2 for the 1920 x 1080 portrait resolution. And the answer was 177 - 178.